# How determine redirect url

Tags: .net, url, redirect

How can I know where a url gets redirected programatically?

e.g. This url:

**http://scobleizer.com/feed/**

redirects to the following url:

**http://feeds2.feedburner.com/fastcompany/scobleizer**

I am trying to read the xml document of feed. But the following lines of code:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(url);
```

will throw an exeption for the first url:

> System.Net.WebException: The remote
>   server returned an error: (404) Not
>   Found.

Answer (score 1):

That shouldn't throw. It works fine for me:

```
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"http://scobleizer.com/feed/");
```

(has now loaded with the feed)

(**edit**: it **was** working, but now I'm getting 404.... odd)

If you need to *know* the final url, you will possibly have to use `HttpWebRequest` manually.

Comment: I couldn't manage to read the final url using HttpWebRequest, I have to try more

Answer (score 1):

If it gives you a 404 it's likely because the feed generator checks your user-agent or similar, and then responds 404 when it doesn't meet the requirements.

I agree with Marc: Use a WebRequest and check the response, it should be a 301 or 302 (Permanent or temporary redirect) and it will contain the target url then.

If your response code isn't 301 or 302, then it's not redirecting you - again this could be caused by a user-agent check serverside.